# Why do the engines on a 737 have a flattened lower surface?

Tags: aerodynamics, jet-engine, boeing-737

Inspired by [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/35212/2265) answer.

The engines on a 737 are not perfectly circular when viewed from the front. The bottom of them are flattened a bit.

[image]

Why is that? Is it for aerodynamic or ground clearance reasons?